# HTML5 wrapper for old browsers, Modernizr

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML5.  It appears that Modernizr and a massive array of "HTML5 shims" provide bits of HTML5 support for older browsers.

But what if I'm lazy and I don't want to even think about older browsers?  Which HTML5 features can be perfectly emulated and which cannot?

Comment: BTW, from what I've read so far Modernizr is more of a "detector" of HTML5 feature availability (in that browser) than a "fixer".

Answer (score 3):

If you're new to HTML5, you should read everything on [DiveIntoHTML5.ep.io](http://www.diveintohtml5.ep.io/).